# SSH to server fails intermittently with correct password

Tags: ssh

I am using MobaXterm to connect to a CentOS server from a Windows machine. My username and password is saved by MobaXterm. Sometimes when I try opening an ssh session with the server it works and connects to the server using the save credentials, while other times it says Access denied and prompts me for my password. At this point entering my password doesn't work and keeps saying "Access denied", but if I restart the session it's another coin-flip of it will work and connect without prompting me. After 4 or 5 tries of starting a session with the saved credentials it always works, so this isn't a blocker but definitely strange.

The ip address is static.

What could be causing this intermittent failures?

Comment: (1) "The ip address is static." – Do you mean the IP address of the server? Do you use the IP address to connect? (2) What is the CentOS server? Is it possible there are multiple servers and some load balancing mechanism lets you reach a random one each time? Maybe due to misconfiguration or whatever only some of the servers accept your credentials.

Comment: One odd possibility: *SSL* (as opposed to *SSH*) depends on time synchronization. If the clock of server or client is a bit off, connection fails - the limit is about 600 or 900 seconds. Whether *SSH* has similar requirement, I do not know.